# How to convert character to date in r with February as the month?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert some characters into date formats. I have so far used as.Date, anytime, sprtime,as.POSIXct. For all of these functions it is possible to convert the characters to dates except when it comes to the second month of the year (February). For example, when I use `as.Date("1978/2/30")` I get the following error message:`Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`
. Then, if a specify the format, I get NAs: `as.Date("1978/2/30","%Y/%m/%d")`. What is curious is that for any other month of the year it works perfectly:`as.Date("1978/3/30","%Y/%m/%d")` gives `as.Date("1978/3/30","%Y/%m/%d")`. Does anyone understand what  I am missing?

Comment: February does not have 30.. sorry

Comment: There is no 30th February, but it looks like if you use a format mask you get NA back from such invalid dates, so just use the mask.

Comment: Shame on me! I have been passing 03 hours on a so basic issue